# Where to connect a C wire for my smart thermostat

Tags: hvac, heating, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to connect the c wire but I'm at a crossroads of sorts. I have a dual zone so there are 2 thermostat wires come into what looks like a relay box ( see pictures) I have located the thermostat wires but I do t know where to connect the extra wire as there is nothing that indicates where the connection is[image][image]

Comment: Can you get us the model number off that zone board please?

Comment: The model number is AR861

Comment: Per wiring diagram page 10 https://argocontrols.com/sites/default/files/AR861-2II%20AR861-3II%20IOM.pdf there is no terminal for connecting a "C" wire.  If you want help with options please furnish the model of stat you are trying to install.

Comment: Ecobee smart thermostat

Comment: Is your system heating-only on both zones, or are you trying to control a cooling setup as well?

Comment: Yes my system is heating only on both zones not trying to add a cooling setup

Comment: The c terminal is present on one one of the solder points  in the empty relay position (i'm not sure which one - show the other side of the circuit board). Tapping that point may void several warranties.

Answer (score 0):

Ecobee has a Power Extender Kit and a lot of documentation on what to do when you don't have a C wire. See: https://support.ecobee.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009155051-Installing-your-ecobee-thermostat-with-the-Power-Extender-Kit-no-C-wire-

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: https://support.ecobee.com/hc/en-us/articles/227874667-Heat-only-2-wire-boiler-furnace-installations "Note: You will not be able to install the Power Extender Kit (PEK) with heat-only 2-wire systems. The PEK can only be used on furnace or heat pump systems that do not have a C wire — this is because the PEK requires R (power), G (fan), and Y (compressor) wires to operate, and these 2-wire heat-only systems do not have these G and Y wires." The Argo uses two-wire dry contact thermostats.

Answer (score 0):

In your installation documents from Ecobee find the diagram for Taco sr503-4, that is functionally equivalent to your Argo control board. The "t" wires to the left of the diagram connect to the T terminals on the Argo board. You will need parts equivalent to a remote power supply for the Ecobee (see amazon "c wire power supply"), and an isolation relay (like a White Rodgers 90-380).